# register is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I am trying to run a simple Ansible playbook but keep getting the following error and I'm not sure why.

> ERROR: register is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play

Below is the code i am trying to execute

```
---

- name: Get SELinux sestatus
  command: sestatus | grep enforcing | grep 'config file'
  register: sestatus

- name: Check if module1.pp exists
  stat:
    path: bin/module1.pp
  register: module1_pp

- name: Disable SELinux if enforcing
  sudo: yes
  command: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - setenforce 0
    - semodule -i bin/module1.pp
    - setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
  when: sestatus.rc == 0 and module1.stat.exists == true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your entire playbook?  You're missing your `hosts` and `tasks` declaration.

---

```
- hosts: some_hosts
  tasks:

  - name: Get SELinux sestatus
    command: sestatus | grep enforcing | grep 'config file'
    register: sestatus

  - name: Check if module1.pp exists
    stat:
      path: bin/module1.pp
    register: module1_pp

  - name: Disable SELinux if enforcing
    sudo: yes
    command: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - setenforce 0
      - semodule -i bin/module1.pp
      - setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
    when: sestatus.rc == 0 and module1.stat.exists == true
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this fixed my issue